# CRM 2013 - Deadlocks due to internal update queries?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Recently we have upgraded our CRM 4 to CRM 2013. We have around 600 users using it. We are monitoring database performance through one tool and observed couple of deadlocks due to following internal queries:

Query 1: Updating QuoteNumber counter in OrganizationBase table

update OrganizationBase set @currentval = CurrentQuoteNumber, CurrentQuoteNumber = CurrentQuoteNumber + 1 where OrganizationId = @orgid

Query 2: Updating OrderNumber counter in OrganizationBase table

update OrganizationBase set @currentval = CurrentOrderNumber, CurrentOrderNumber = CurrentOrderNumber + 1 where OrganizationId = @orgid

I don't know what will be impact due to these deadlocks because I have found counters are updated correctly till now and all quotes and orders have unique number, so no data issue.

My questions are,

1) Have anybody noticed such issue?

2) Any customizations (like plugins/workflows) creates such issues in internal queries? -

Comment: Do you have any plugins/real-time workflows running during Create of Quote or Order?

Comment: @Nicknow - Yes we have some plugins on create of Quote and Order.

Comment: Do the deadlocks go away if you disable the plugins?